# How can I integrate Touch ID and Face ID in iOS(swift 5) app

Tags: swift5, biometrics, face-id

I have to implement biometric authentication, I am using many demos but none the demo is complete, Can any one suggest me the demo or having the 
 complete demo by which i can register the user biometric and authenticate only that particular user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple Touch IDs on your device and it can be used in your app, but it will work as a single user even if the fingerprints are different.

Apple says the model of your face never leaves your iPhone. It does not transmit it over any network or store it in the cloud. Like your digital Touch ID fingerprint, your Face ID data is stored specifically in something called the iPhone's secure enclave.

For multiple user authentication, you have to store the fingerprints on your particular app. But as per my research, Apple didn't give you an access to the Secure Enclave.

https://www.quora.com/Can-the-iPhone-fingerprint-sensor-be-used-to-create-a-fingerprint-picture

You can refer the documentation from Apple to integrate Face ID and Touch ID with your app for a particular user.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id